# SVN Structure for Jenkins Polling

Tags: svn, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, polling

I need to do polling from SVN in my Continuous Integration Jenkins server . I have configured SVN URL , username and password and given poll interval of one minute .

Currently I have given SVN project trunk URL in my Jenkins job . Everything working fine .

Is right to give SVN trunk in Jenkins or is there a way to poll code whenever a new  code branched in SVN?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a Jenkins job per branch. Or you can try to make a parameterized job that covers all branches. Not sure you would want the latter. At least keep your build artefacts for each branch separate. Avoid distinct branches interfering with oneanother.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins job per branch is a possible scenario, but then there is no **continuos integration** concept to it. I do not actually understand the second part where you said poll code. If you meant to ask whether polling and build in each of the branch you created can be done, it can.

Simply create new job from existing jobs and change the repository branch names. But as I said, there is no Continuos Integration in this as CI basically deals with adding code/enhancements over iterations, build, test,deploy and commit working code to master and REPEAT.